# npm install -g not working while uninstalling react-native-cli?

Tags: react-native, npm

I am trying to uninstall the "react-native-cli" which I use for react-native projects! but I am not able to do so!
My environment is `mac`.

Here is what i have done so far!

Whether I type `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` or `sudo npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`.

The terminal shows: `up to date in 0.041s`

[image]

When I type `react-native init projectName`, it still creates the project.

I think the command `react-native init` should not to work.

Anyone knows how to uninstall `react-native-cli` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the output of uninstalling in terminal? please show the snapshot of it! and where you have been initing the project  can you tell ! maybe you are in the directory of already created react-native project

Comment: Sure, I update my terminal image.  It shows `up to date in 0.041s` when type uninstall command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**SOLUTION ONE** ! 
 not fully sure this will work! but try updating your npm first by doing

`npm install npm`

and after that try uninstalling the cli if that does not work then

**SOLUTION TWO** !

Here is another go around to solve the issue its a bit manual way

**1:** First run this

```
npm list -g
```

this will show the list of installed packages in your user folder

then check . using **command+f** if there is react-native-cil there

then do this

**`open /usr/local/lib/node_modules`**

This will open the root installed packages and you can manually find and delete the **react-native-cli** like this

[image]

Comment: `npm list -g` can't find react-native-cli , but `open /usr/local/lib/node_modules` can see react-native-cli, I drag it to trash. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `yarn`. You can do `yarn global list` then check that if any package contains `react-native`. Then run `yarn global remove <package>` to remove that package.

ex:

```
yarn global remove @react-native-community/cli
```

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall react native CLI using:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```